# Can't access element attribute when it is clearly set

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve.
In my class I set:

```
text.Attributes.Add("oldValue", text.Text);
```

Debugging the code I can see the value is being set properly. When I view the page source with chrome I see the following:

```
<input name="astextMon" type="text" value="4,25" 
       id="textMon" class="inputText"
       autocomplete="on" 
       onfocus="ValidateReadStatus(this.id,this.ValueId);SetFocus(this.id);"
       valueid="408412" 
       oldvalue="4,25" 
       onchange="return GridOnChange('0;0',this,'textMon',1,true);" 
       onkeydown="return GridOnKeyDown(this.id,'0;0');"           
       ondblclick="SetTextPos('0;0');"
>
```

As you can see, the `oldvalue` attribute is set and has the correct value, but if I try to access it I always get `undefined`. Even when accessing the element from the Chrome console.

What am I missing here?

EDIT. The typo in the name attribute happened when placing the code here. That is not the problem. I think case sensitivity is also not the issue, because when I remove:

```
text.Attributes.Add("oldValue", text.Text);
```

from my class, the oldvalue="4,25" property dissapears from the element. I also tried to change oldValue to oldvalue, but the same problem remains.

I am trying to access the object by using

```
alert(element.oldvalue) or alert(element["oldvalue"]) or 
alert(element["oldValue"]) or alert(element["oldValue"]) none work.
```

If I type `alert(element.value)` It correctly alerts the value attribute.

Comment: How are you trying to access the value?

Comment: I have edited my post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that in your code snippet the input tag is not valid, after name attribute you must add a quote char.

```
<input name="astextMon" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

missing the first quote in `name=astextMon"` change it to `name="astextMon"`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive:
`... oldvalue="4,25" ...`
and
`text.Attributes.Add("oldValue", text.Text);`
refer to 2 **different** attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get the attribute define by you:

```
document.getElementById('textMon').attributes['oldvalue'].value;
```

Where you will get: `oldvalue: 4,25`

Few more things:

1. `name=astextMon"` should be `name="astextMon"`

Comment: See my comment. Your suggestion also results in undefined

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved my problem by using

```
$(element).attr("oldValue");
```

I have no idea why when using JQuery I can access the attribute just fine, but without it it is undefined. If anyone has an answer I would love to hear it.